# React Native get dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

there is a data which is changing every second in my api and i should get it dynamically to react native screen and im using setInterval
I writed a function which is send request and get data every second and i should refresh this function and i did use setInterval but im not sure about that is this healthy? also i could not solve this because i got an error that :

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 7):
    TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function. (In '_this2.setState({
        kalanzaman: res.data
    })', '_this2.setState' is undefined)
```

My func and how am i calling it :

```
  dynamically() {
    // console.log("bom")
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/kalanzaman`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ kalanzaman: res.data })
      })
  }
```

.

```
setInterval(this.dynamically, 1000)
```

Which way should i use for get dynamic data to react native from my api?

Comment: your example doesnt work because you forgot to bind this: setInterval(this.dynamically.bind(this), 1000)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Http request, you can use Websocket.
It is a two-way interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server.
for example: have a look at [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)

Comment: actually it works anymore but probably i should use socket for performance , http requests in every second is not good idea i thinkt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better if you write it like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  dynamically() {
    // console.log("bom")
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/kalanzaman`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ kalanzaman: res.data })
      }).catch((error) => {
        alert('Something Error')
     })
  } 
}, 100);
```

You must cath() for catching the error, and put it on **componentDidMount**